# Adding New Subscription policy in WSO2 API Manager and Applying on API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've tried creating a new subscription throttling policy(10req/min). I've selected the same while publishing an API, and also selected the same in-store while subscribing to an API. But still, it's taking more than 10req/min.

Note: we are using 2 nodes in a cluster environment.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to not synching the throttling conditions in both nodes. Therefore, in this scenario, each node will serve 10 req/min. Total, 20 req/min.

To fix this, you should publish throttling events from each node to both the nodes.

Node 1 - publishes to Node 1 and Node 2

Node 2 - publishes to Node 2 and Node 1.

This way, both the nodes have the throttle events so that, the throttle decision will be taken properly.

In each node, you have to do the following configuration

```
<ThrottlingConfigurations>
        <EnableAdvanceThrottling>true</EnableAdvanceThrottling>
        <DataPublisher>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Type>Binary</Type>
            <ReceiverUrlGroup>{tcp://node1_ip:9612, tcp://node2_ip:9612}</ReceiverUrlGroup>
            <!--ReceiverUrlGroup>tcp://${carbon.local.ip}:9612</ReceiverUrlGroup-->
            <AuthUrlGroup>{ssl://node1_ip:9712, ssl://node2_ip:9713}</AuthUrlGroup>
            <!--AuthUrlGroup>ssl://${carbon.local.ip}:9712</AuthUrlGroup-->
            <Username>${admin.username}</Username>
</ThrottlingConfigurations>
```

Comment: Hi Menaka,
We have a fully distributed API Manager environment, to which node we have to make configurations? Either to Publisher, Gateway, Traffic Manager node?